# Photo changing every day(Xcode, Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift

I haven't write code for this But I want some help that can it be possible to code so that it shows new photo everyday. for example I have 10 images and I want to display each image for like September 16,17,18, and so on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...
Call method getImageForToday() where ever you want to fetch image for today (This solution will work specific to your case, i.e. as you mentioned you have 10 images)

```
func getImageForToday() -> UIImage
{
  let arrImages = ["image1.png", "image2.png" ... "image10.png"]

  var imageName = arrImages[getLastCharacterFromTodayDate()]
  return UIImage(named: imageName)

}







func getLastCharacterFromTodayDate() -> Int
    {
         let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier:          NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!

        let component = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: NSDate())

        return component.day % 10
    }
```

Comment: if i want it to repeat after 10 days the same image ? @alijawad

Comment: it will repeat images after 10 days like image1.png will be displayed on date 1, 11, 21, 31... image2.png will be displayed on day 2, 12, and 22.. and so on

Comment: Thanks alot and one more thing if we wamt the same with the UILabel to repeat.All the procedure is same ? @alijawad

Comment: You need to replace method "getImageForToday" with following
func getLabelForToday() -> UILabel
{
  let arrTexts = ["text1", "text2" ... "text3"]

  var text = arrImages[getLastCharacterFromTodayDate()]
var lb = UILabel()

   lb.text = text

return lb

}

Comment: following ? Getlabelfortoday ?

Comment: I have edited my previous comment, let me know if you are still not clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90386/discussion-between-ali-jawad-and-motivation-gym5).

Comment: Can you help me in writing a code like how we can display array of texts in a fixed manner(not random)

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: like i want to display many texts in one label in a fixed way for example var texts = ["1","2"] now i want it to display in a  fixed way like whenever i press a button it shows 1 and then when i press it again it shows 2 something like that will you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the object NSDate to know what day is it and after that doing something.

First you have your dictionnary of image like that :

```
let images = [ UIImage(named: "image1.png")!, UIImage(named: "image2.png")!, UIImage(named: "image3.png")]
```

so now, you must know what day is it for the first app openning in exemple.
So you can do that :

```
let date = NSDate()
```

You put the element date in UserDefaults. (in order to save it)

You can now display a image. You make a random number and you take UIImage at this random position.

The day after, or the next app opening you recheck the NSDate with the NSDate saved and if it's different you take a other photo.